# C# how to count how many numbers in an array that are not within a specifc number

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, count, boolean

the input is like this

```
100 5 
0 10
0 5
75 95
12 17
13 14
```

and the output is `65`
so i want the program to count which numbers from 0-100 are not in the array.

this is how i started

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
    int roadlength = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Split(" ")[0]);
    int stagecnt = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Split(" ")[1]);
    int[] startpoint = new int[stagecnt];
    int[] endpoint = new int[stagecnt];
    int km = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stagecnt; i++)
    {
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        startpoint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input2.Split(' ')[0]);
        endpoint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input2.Split(' ')[1]);
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < stagecnt; i++)
    {
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where you struggled with, for what is the variable `roadlength` used, so the first number in each line? The input that you have shown, is that input1 or input2(in the loop)?

Comment: You might eloborate more on what you want. I have no idea why the result should be 65 so you might want to explain that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's count distinct numbers that are in `0..100` range and then subtract from total number in `0..100` range:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] data = new int[] {
  100, 5, 0, 10, 0, 5, 75, 95, 12, 17, 13, 14,
};

...

int min = 0;
int max = 100;

int result = max - min + 1 - data
  .Where(item => item >= min && item <= max)
  .Distinct()
  .Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are complicating the problem, it's very simple.

Initialize an array/list with the given range.
and check all your input items one by one whether they are present in the first carry. and if not present then just increment the count.

though complexity is high but its simplest solution.

```
int[] items = ;
int start = 1;
int end = 100;

int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (!items.Contains(arr[i]))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count missing integers in your array, compared to all between 1 and 100:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
HashSet<int> allBetween1And100 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToHashSet();
allBetween1And100.ExceptWith(array); // removes all from the set which are not in array
int countMissing = allBetween1And100.Count; // 95
```

The advantage of this approach is that you even have a collection with the missing. Of course this needs some memory, so if you don't need them, prefer a simple loop.